# Behaviour of product of Bessel functions $Y_n(z)J_n(z)$?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, limits, special-functions, bessel-functions

I'm interested in the the behaviour of product

$$Y_m(z)J_m(z)$$

as a function of $m \in \mathbb{R}_+$, for fixed, real $z > 0$?

Here, $ J_m(z)$ and $Y_m(z)$ are Bessel functions of the first and second kind and order $m$, respectively.

Numerical computation suggests it goes to zero as $m \to \infty$, and the asymptotic expansions in Abramowitz and Stegun (p. 365) confirms this.
However, I am more interested in the behaviour in the non-asymptotic situation.

There is a huge amount of literature on Bessel functions, but I somehow cannot seem to find anything concerning the behaviour of the particular product above. All help is much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by behavior? What particular properties of this product as a function of $m$ are you interested in? For which values of $z$?

Comment: For example monotonicity and convexity and when its decreasing or increasing. All non-negative, real values of $z$ and $m$ are of interest, but in particular the range when $m$ is such that $y_{m,1} > z$, i.e., in the region where $Y_n(z)$ is strictly decreasing. ($y_{m,1}$ is the first root of $Y_m(z)$)